# How can a React Component trigger the function of a sibling React Component

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have the following react code.

```
<Navigation parentWindow={this} />
<p>Sub Pages</p>
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    component="div"
    transitionName="page-transition"
    transitionEnterTimeout={0}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
  >
      {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
          key: location.pathname
      })}
  </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

The `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` will eventually render a `<ContactPage />` which is created by a `ContactPage.js`.  Here's what `ContactPage.js` looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Page extends React.Component
{
    testMe() {alert('Hello World!');}
    render() {return <div>Hello</div>;}
}
```

From my `<Navigation />` which is created by `Navigation.js`, I want to be able to trigger the  `ContactPage.testMe()`.  So I did this in my `Navigation.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Page extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        this.props.parentWindow.props.children.testMe();
        return <div>Navigate me</div>;
    }
}
```

But when I run the project, my Navigation gives me the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.parentWindow.props.children.testCall
```

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: You have `export default class Page extends React.Component` in your Navigation.js. Is that just a copy and paste mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could achieve this by using `refs`. In the ParentWindow component you would assign a `ref` to the cloned children, that you would then pass as a prop to the navigation.

React works a bit different than other JS libraries and it forces you to move your business logic, or event logic to the parent component and pass it down as props. What I would suggest is that you pass in a callback function to the Navigation page, that when triggered it calls the ContactPage method.

```
class Navigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    this.props.onAlertParent();
    return <div>Navigate me</div>;
  }
}

class ParentWindow extends Component {
  alertChild() {
    if (this.childNode && this.childNode.testMe) {
      this.childNode.testMe();
    }
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <Navigation onAlertParent={() => this.alertChild()} />
      <p>Sub Pages</p>
      <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
        component="div"
        transitionName="page-transition"
        transitionEnterTimeout={0}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={500}
      >
        {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
          key: location.pathname,
          ref: (node) => { this.childNode = node; }
        })}
      </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Notice how the `Navigation` component receives a callback function via the props, the navigation element doesn't need to know anything about its siblings, it's communicating to them using the parent.

**The react way** is to communicate between components using props by passing either data or callbacks. There is always a better way to communicate than calling element methods. Even the approach I suggested is **flawed** since it's still calling a method from an element.